Switching battery bank between 12 V and 24 V
Looking to add a couple of 12 V batteries to a camper. Everything (plus charging) runs off 12 V except a 700 W stove which runs off 24 V which I'd like to be able to run for short periods. The cost of adding a buck booster isn't cheap, so I'd like to be able to temporarily switch to 24 V for cooking.
To avoid the batteries getting too far out of balance when switched to 24 V, I'd like to disconnect charging and most of the other loads while cooking, otherwise I'm concerned it'll have the potential for large amps between the two batteries when recombined in parallel. For safety I'll also be running different Anderson plugs for different items so it shouldn't be possible to feed 24 V to a 12 V item.
I've come up with the below circuit which seems fairly simple and robust, but wanted to get someone with some more circuit knowledge to run their eye over it?
Edited for clarity and updated circuit so it might actually work now.


Sorry, I should clarify the resistors are just to indicate where the loads connect. R1 would be 12V and R2 would be 24V. I just realised this circuit wouldn't work well anyway as the diode prevents the batteries balancing when in 12V mode. BAT2 would charge, but not discharge.

Ahh, this makes a lot more sense - I was wondering if you were trying to do "passive cell balancing". Please feel free to revise your question with new info / updated schematic!

Thanks @Attie, I've updated the schematic to a new design which I think might work. I've tried to label the outputs this time but the labels go a bit astray when inserting it.

If the batteries become unbalanced while you are in series mode, you can get some very high currents flowing when you connect them back in parallel. Balancing them with a resistor before going back to parallel mode is probably a good idea. Also, fuses in front of each battery is also a good idea. If something goes wrong with the switch, you don't want to have two batteries shorted.

Can they become unbalanced in series mode with only 24v loads? That was why I was thinking it'd be best to disconnect all 12v draws while in series mode. It'd usually only be in series for maybe 15-30 minutes at a time. Things like lights are multivolt so with some small diodes can be wired into both sides of the circuit and operate consistently. Was definitely going to have fuses on both batteries, just didn't bother including them on the schematic.

Yes, they can get unbalanced. The chance for that increases if they are different brand/model/capacity/age etc. When connecting batteries in parallel, it is a good idea to do that with a low-ohm power resistor first, and only connect them in parallel after the voltage over (and current through) that resistor is zero.

IMO, this is a terrible idea. I would either get a 24V battery and charger for the 24V load and run that independently. Or, put the 2 12V batteries in series with independent chargers that are floating across each battery: put the 24V load across both of them, and split the 12V circuits between the 12V batteries:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Any other scheme is going to be a kludge.

An elegant solution which makes me feel dumb for not thinking of it! My only issue is I need to charge both batteries from a single solar panel, I can't run MPPT in parrallel though. Could I charge from solar at 24V in series and have two small chargers from the alternator to keep them in balance? Or charge one battery from the other with an isolated charger?

@Tom What kind of outputs does the MPPT convertor have?

I haven't purchased anything other than a 475W solar panel yet. I'm thinking maybe a Victron 100/20 MPPT and a Victron Battery Balancer might do the trick? Plus either a 24V boost charger or two small 12V DCDC chargers from the alternator.

@Tom you should have stated the solar panel complication in your description. What you are suggesting might work but is not very elegant - the balancer basically wastes energy to balance the batteries. Will it work? Probably. Will it be efficient? Only if your lucky - the loads have to stay perfectly balanced so the battery balancer is effectively not doing anything. You should see if you can find a MPPT with two separate output channels. Or you might be able to put two battery chargers on the output of the MPPT. Again, the chargers have to be floating or they short out.

@Tom This circuit will kill your batteries in no time due to significant imbalance.

Your proposed circuit will damage the batteries due to the inrush of current when connected in parallel.
The other proposed circuit will damage the batteries due to the imbalance caused by the unequal current draw in the bottom and top circuits. The 24 V load will drain the remaining charge from one battery while over-discharging and reversing (!) the other battery.
Instead, you must use a DC-DC converter to go from 12 V to 24 V or vice versa.
12 V solution (if the 12 V loads take more power than the 24 V loads):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
24 V solution (if the 24 V loads take more power than the 12 V loads):

simulate this circuit
Boating industry solution (uses an equalizer aka balancer, which is a 24 V to 12 V DC-DC converter):

simulate this circuit

Option 3 is cleatly the grasping hand (for those that don't get it it this means best answer) U1 only needs to supply half the average 12V load current.
